# Is electrical conductivity of a material measured separately from resistivity?

Tags: material-science

I'm trying to determine the electrical conductivity of Hiperco 50 and 1018 steel, but often times on data sheets I only see resistivity data entered. **Can I simply take the inverse of this value, or is there a more involved process?** I noticed in some documents that they specify when they have a unique value for conductivity versus when they just take the inverse of resistivity.

Comment: What documents?

Comment: @Pieter [here is one such document](https://www.nde-ed.org/GeneralResources/MaterialProperties/ET/Conductivity_Iron.pdf). see the "notes" column

Comment: This is just a matter of sourcing and references. Probably the ASM Metals Handbook only gives the resistivity value, whereas the eddy current sources give both values in the text of the reference. All values follow $\sigma = 1/\varrho.$

Answer (score 1):

The specific electrical conductivity $\sigma$ of the materials is just the inverse of the specific electrical resistivity $\rho$: $$\sigma=\frac {1}{\rho}$$  Thus if you have the resistivities you can easily calculate the conductivities.

Comment: I think in practice the term resistivity is only the inverse of the dc-conductivity.  The conductivity itself is complex (in the Fourier domain) and dispersive.

Comment: @JohnScales - I don't understand why you want to restrict the inverse relation between conductivity and resistivity to DC. It would also hold for a complex ac resistivity. But this is completely irrelevant for the OP's question here which is obviously about specific DC conductivity and resistivity data of different steels.

Comment: I have no strong opinion on the matter @freecharly.  But I looked it up in two of the standard physics grad-texts, and that is the convention they use.  I see no reference in the OP to DC.

Comment: @JohnScales - The OP refers to data sheets of common materials (steels). Such data sheets usually give DC resistivities or conductivities. And his question is, whether, in general, the conductivity is the inverse of the resistivity. And the answer is yes, even for the AC case, which, however, is obviously irrelevant here.

Comment: All my data sheets are above 100 GHz.  That's where I work! I try not to make assumptions about what the OP "really" meant.  This is beside the point that standard texts use the DC convention for resistivity.  Maybe in EE it's different.

Comment: @JohnScales - This is no surprise if you work in the optical field and look at optical materials data  sheets. I don't understand what your point is concerning my answer to the OP's question referring to steel data sheets.

Comment: I've already answered that but:  1) you're assuming the data sheets are DC.  Maybe they are, who knows?  and 2) the convention in standard texts is to reserve the term resistivity for the inverse of the dc-conductivity.  If however, you're only interested in DC, then no problem.  As I said, I try to take the posts at face value and not assume I know what the author "really" meant.  Let's leave it at that shall we?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76031/discussion-between-john-scales-and-freecharly).